# Linear recurrence for a sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am new to linear recurrence theory. I want to find a linear recurrence for the sequence $f_{n}$ where $f_{n}$ is the number of subsets $G'\subset G(P_{n})$ where each pair of vertices in $G'$ are neither adjacent nor have a common neighbour.

Here $P_{n}$ means a chordless path with $n$ vertices and $G(P_{n})$ is the set of vertices $\{G_{1},...,G_{n}\}$. I don't know how to proceed, any kind of hints would be appreciated. I think I need to use the adjacency matrix here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, it's basically a subset of a path where the chosen vertices have to be at least distance 3 from each other.

Given a path of length $n$, we can iterate on the first vertex to be present in our subset. We can choose the first vertex in the subset to be:

1. The first vertex in the path (after which, we have $f_{n-3}$ ways to choose the remaining)
2. The second vertex in the path (after which, we have $f_{n-4}$ ways to choose the remaining)
3. The third vertex in the path (after which, we have $f_{n-5}$ ways to choose the remaining)
4. None of the first three vertices (after which, we have $f_{n-3}$ ways to choose the remaining)

Note that these 4 cases are disjoint and also cover all possibilities. Thus,

$f_n = f_{n-3} + f_{n-4} + f_{n-5} + f_{n-3}$

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize it was so simple.

Comment: wait actually i think I made it unnecessarily complicated. it's just f_n-3 + f_n-1, because we can either pick the first vertex or not pick it.

Comment: but it's still the same, thanks anyway.